# h:commandLink inside h:dataTable not invoked

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, commandlink

I have a `commandLink` inside a `dataTable` as below:

```
<h:column>
    <h:commandLink action="#{pc_jlReport.JoinerleaveReportViewButton}">
        <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/theme/default/images/view.png" alt="" title="" border="0" />
        <f:param name="JLReportId" value="#{JLReport.idJoinerLeaver}"></f:param>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:column>
```

It should invoke this method:

```
public String JoinerleaveReportViewButton() {
    try {
        jlr = JoinerLeaverReportManager.getInstance().JoinerleaveReportViewButton(new Long(getRequestParam("JLReportId").toString()));
        return Constants.AVIEW;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Constants.FAILURE;
    }
}
```

But it is not invoked. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: does `Constants.AVIEW` return *aview* ? Have you confirmed that `Constants.AVIEW` is returned and not `Constants.FAILURE` ? Is there any exception ? Is this path really correct : `/admin/report/ResultofJoinerLeaverReport.jsp` ? Have you tried to put a print in your method to make sure it is even reached ?

Comment: acctually the problem is that on commandLink action it is not going to pagecontroller function i checked it by System.out.println("hello"); but that didn't got printed mean commandLink is not moving to pageController

Comment: Is your commandLink in an `h:form` ?

Comment: yes it is between <h:form prependId="false"> </h:form>

Comment: Are you sure you refer to the correct bean ? `pc_jlReport` or `JLReport` ? Have you verified that they are correctly managed/named ?

Comment: yes i'm sure through same bean i'm generating report!

Comment: <h:commandButton value="Generate Report" action="#{pc_jlReport.JoinerleaveReportGenerationButton}" styleClass="form_submit" type="submit" ></h:commandButton>

Comment: and that commandButton function properly ?

Comment: Perhaps you have nested form (that could also be caused by inclusion, hard to say without seeing your code) ?

Comment: yes! it is working working properly

Comment: I see that your link is in a column, is the column inside a `dataTable` or `ui:repeat` or any other iterable ?

Comment: i'm not using nested forms!!

Comment: What about iterable components ?

Comment: i believe there is no issue with iterable components, i'm using the same code in another page and jsp but for different report(database values) which is correctly working there!!!

Comment: If really it is the same code, then try doing a clean and build on your project. Perhaps the new faces-config.xml was not deployed.

Comment: i cleaned and rebuilt project almost 30-40 time :D

Comment: Argh, maybe there is any rendered attributes on parent components that could have evaluated to false during previous JSF execution phase ?

Comment: You might also want to check the JS console, I've already experienced a case where jsf's js were not properly loaded which was causing an un-triggered action.

Comment: believe me there is non :v

Comment: that's the issue each and everything is fine i checked each and everything more than 30 times but found nothing worng!! still having same issue just at two locations and on remaining location same code is working fine!

Comment: that might be a problem tell me how can i check JS console!

Comment: Have you declared `<h:head>` at the top of your class ? even if it is empty, it is needed for jsf's js to load.

Comment: To check the console on Chrome, right click in page , click on inspect element then click on the las tab (console).

Comment: lol yea i did that obviously :p

Comment: ohh that one yes i checked that but i found no error there!

Comment: Then I would try to put the commandLink outside of it parent component (outside of any iterable) just to see if it works there.